# Copying text from Vim to something else without clipboard support of Vim

Tags: vim

I've tried to copy text from Vim window to somewhere but it doesn't work.
Decisions which I've found with google didn't help too. For instance, using the registers "* and "+.

Command vim version is (Ubuntu 12.04. Vim 7.3):

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

Can you help me to solve it? Should I use other vim version or are there any methods to copy text from Vim to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be using `vim-tiny`.

Do

```
$ vim --version | grep version
```

and report back the result.

If you are using "tiny", you should install a proper version.

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

and/or

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: I've installed vim-gnome and now Vim supports clipboard. "* and other methods is available. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Better if you just install fuller version of vim with all necessary stuff compiled in. But if you can’t do this for some reason then you have at least two options: open file in something else (like gedit) and copy from there or use `xclip` or `xsel` to put required text to the clipboard. Example usage:

```
:'<,'>w !xclip -i
```

to send a visually selected range of lines to clipboard (by default: primary/mouse buffer referred as `*` in vim, use `-sel clip` additional arguments to change this to clipboard one referred as `+`) and

```
:call system('xclip -i', @")
```

to send a default (`"`) register contents to clipboard.